# Add emoji on google chat message

Tags: google-chat

How can i add an emoji on google chat message?
At the moment, we create a google chat message using webhoock, but, we need to attach a emoji to classify message for another team. Reading official doc, i do not find way to add emoji on message.
Some forums say to using a tag "emoji" on request body, but, does not exist.

I tried to add emoji using <emoji/:emoji-tag:>, but not work

Add emoji tag on request body and create another field in request data called emoji, but does not worke